# Twitter4j API Posting 2 Tweet with same content on Single Request

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

When I tweet via twitter4j API, sometimes a tweet is posted twice when doing a request. This happens rarely and doesn't throw any exception. What could be the reason?

Comment: Use Fiddler or another HTTP traffic monitor to see if the request is being sent twice.